# Am I using "and so are" correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Our world is constantly changing and so are people.

Comment: Basically, yes. But I'd add a comma after _changing_, and insert _its_ before _people_ to enhance the parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

> Our world is constantly changing and so are people.

Means that the world is changing and so are all people, on the world or off it.  Re-phrasing as the following reads better:

- > Our world is changing, and so are its people.
- > Our world is changing and so are the people.
- > Our world and its people are changing.
- > Our world and the people are changing.

Though, the sentence you wrote is correct, as a sentence.